# 17.10 add Japanese input

Tags: 17.10, input-method, japanese, fcitx

Tried to add `fcitx-mozc` module to input Japanese on **17.10**

```
apt install fcitx-mozc
```

then set the input method to <kbd>**fcitx ▾**</kbd>

But for some reason "日本語 Mozc" does not appear in the Input Sources (Text Entry).
(this after trying several times, rebooting in between)

It seems being on 17.10 makes a difference.

Is there another module to install?
Or maybe 17.10 does not support `fcitx-mozc`?

Comment: Did you try to follow instructions  posted here https://askubuntu.com/questions/791834/japanese-input-on-16-04-with-fcitx-and-mozc

Comment: This is one of the page I was using ... Did install Japanese anthy on 16.04 in the past and had no problem. This is for a Japanese friend who wants fcitx-mozc.

Comment: @JacekHerbrych: Those instructions seem to be obsolete for Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Try 16.04.4 LTS + fcitx-mozc.   Xubuntu 17.10 + fcitx-mozc.   or 17.10 unity (Ubuntu desktop) + ibus-mozc.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.10 is based on GNOME, and GNOME doesn't support Fcitx well. Unless your friend is using the Unity desktop, it's probably wise to advise them to install and use `ibus-mozc` instead.

(There is no "Text Entry" on your friend's 17.10, right?)

*Edit:*

Otherwise, to use `fcitx-mozc` on Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME, it can be enabled from the *Fcitx Config Tool*. Not sure how well it works, though. If `fcitx-mozc` is considered important, your friend may want to switch to a non-GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks but `ibus-mozc` was installed already (default, probably), and there is no added Japanese "input source" that could be used, then. What would be the next step?

Comment: @RingØ: See my edited answer.